# Move an object to the position of the user's touch in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to have an object move to the position of the user's touch.

This is my approach to solving the problem:

```
public float speed = 1.5f;
public Rigidbody2D ball;
bool hasMoved = false;
Vector2 point;

void Start()
{
    ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    ball.gravityScale = 0;
    Vector2 point = Vector2.zero;
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && !hasMoved)
    {
        hasMoved = true;
        Vector2 point = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(point.x - transform.position.x, point.y - transform.position.y);
        StartCoroutine(Lancio(direction));
        ball.gravityScale = 80;
    }
}

IEnumerator Lancio(Vector2 direction)
{
    ball.AddForce(direction.normalized * speed);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.03f);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work properly?

Comment: How did it not work properly? Did you get any errors?